# Event-based sampling with the perf userland tool and PEBS

Tags: linux-kernel, profiling, kernel-module, perf

I'm doing event-based sampling with the perf userland tool: the objective being trying to find out where certain performance-impacting events like branch misses and cache misses are occurring on a larger system I'm working on.

Now, something like

```
perf record -a -e branch-misses:pp -- sleep 5
```

works perfectly: the PEBS counting mode trigerred by the 'pp' modifier is really accurate when collecting the IP in the samples.

Unfortunately, when I try to do the same for cache-misses, i.e.

```
perf record -a -e cache-misses:pp -- sleep 5 # [1]
```

I get

> Error: sys_perf_event_open() syscall returned with 22 (Invalid argument).  /bin/dmesg may provide additional information.
>
> Fatal: No CONFIG_PERF_EVENTS=y kernel support configured?

`dmesg | grep "perf\|pmu"` shows nothing useful AFAICT. I'm also pretty sure that the kernel was compiled with CONFIG_PERF_EVENTS=y because both [1] and

```
perf record -a -e cache-misses -- sleep 5 # [2]
```

work : the problem with [2] being that the collected samples are not very accurate, which hurts my profiles.

Any hints on what could be going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out the specific event that the generic `cache-misses` maps to does not support PEBS. An alternative is to use one of the events that **are** supported by PEBS (see the list for the Nehalem architecture [here](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/amplifierxe/en-us/2011Update/lin/ug_docs/reference/index.htm#pmn/events/about_precise_event_based_sampling_performance_tuning_events.html)) with an appropriate mask to narrow it down. Specifically, one could use MEM_LOAD_RETIRED:LLC_MISS, even though the event doesn't seem to be accurate on all occasions.

Comment: The link to the list of events for Nehalem is broken. A new link in a different location is https://download.01.org/perfmon/NHM-EP/NehalemEP_core_V1.json