# Error when use perf with dwarf call-graph: Invalid argument for event

Tags: linux, events, kernel, profiling, perf

I'm trying to profile my programs. The call `perf record --call-graph=fp` using frame-pointers works fine. But the call `perf record --call-graph=dwarf` gives and error

```
WARNING: Kernel address maps (/proc/{kallsyms,modules}) are 
restricted, check /proc/sys/kernel/kptr_restrict.

Samples in kernel functions may not be resolved if a suitable vmlinux
file is not found in the buildid cache or in the vmlinux path.

Samples in kernel modules won't be resolved at all.

If some relocation was applied (e.g. kexec) symbols may be misresolved
even with a suitable vmlinux or kallsyms file.

Error:
The sys_perf_event_open() syscall returned with 22 (Invalid argument)     
for event (cycles:ppp).
/bin/dmesg may provide additional information.
No CONFIG_PERF_EVENTS=y kernel support configured
```

I'm sure that my kernel config has right flag, so the issue is somewhere else. I found a similar [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11440182/event-based-sampling-with-the-perf-userland-tool-and-pebs) about the topic. It says that some events are not available in the CPU. But why farme-pointer based profile works? I found [PEBS table](http://oprofile.sourceforge.net/docs/intel-haswell-events.php) for my Haswell CPU. How can I be sure that something is forbidden? Or the problem is located somewhere else?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. I don't know enough about the kernel to go further. I just wan't to be able to check where my program is spending its time… An answer to this question would help me a lot.

Comment: I have this same problem on Ubuntu 16.04 after upgrading to kernel 4.8.0.  The 4.4.0 kernel works fine with dwarf.